# Make section and main the same height as it's content (fullpage)

Tags: html, css, fullpage.js

Is there a way to make my sections the same height as its content? I've tried to change section to `section fp-auto-height`but the section ends up squeezing the whole page down to like `30px`. Even though I have content within `section` with preset heights.

```css
.mainupp {
  background-color: #e8e8e8;
}
#main {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: bottom;
  background-size: cover;
}
#mid-text {
  margin: auto;
  text-align: left;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  background-size: auto;
}
.dark-text p {
  font-size: 14pt;
  color: #7e7e7e;
  font-family: Calibri;
  line-height: 130%;
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div class="section fp-auto-height" data-menuanchor="thirdPage">
  <div class="slide">
    <div id="main" class="mainupp">
      <div id="myheader" class="border"></div>
      <div class="container-fluid height-full">
        <div class="row">
          <div id="head-text">
            <div class="col-sm-5"></div>
            <div class="col-sm-2">
              <h2>sdfsdfsdf</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-5"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div id="mid-text" class="dark-text">
            <div class="col-sm-5"></div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
              <p>asd asd asd as das dasdas d asd as d asd as d asd as d asd as da sd asdasdasdasd as d asdas das d asdasdasd asdas da sd asd as da sd asd as d as asdasdasdasdasd</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="meny" class="menyupp"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Your sections are as tall as their content. The problem is: `top: 10%;` that is set on `#mid-text`. It's making the sections overlap each other.

Comment: Do you mean "Why the height of section does not equal the height of mid-text"?

Comment: tried to remove it but its still the same. the page gets as big as the `<div class="slide">` arrows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you are using `position: absolute`. Use a container within the section and set the height in that container.

```
<div class="section">
    <div class="my-container">
       WHATEVER HERE
     </div>
</div>
```

Then in the css:

```
.my-container{
     height: 1200px;
}
```

Comment: hm ok thank you that seems to work, but shouldn't it work the same with `<div id="mid-text"`

Comment: I don't care which selector you use to set the CSS property. Use whatever, but  do it right :)

Comment: no need to get upset i'm just trying to understand :), i thought since my `<div id="mid-text"` has a preset height of 300px my section would follow it

Comment: wups missed the part with `position: absolute`:O

Comment: Not upset, just saying that no matter what selector you use :D